# Local Drupal installation can't copy files to another computer on network

Tags: files

I want to use file_copy to copy a file from Drupal public directory to a shared folder of another

computer on the same network.
I can access the shared folder by Finder (Drupal is installed on

MAMP) but coping files in that directory gives me the same error:

> The specified file public://file.pdf 
>   could not be copied, because the destination directory is not properly configured. This may be
>   caused by a problem with file or directory permissions. More information is available in the system log.

The shared folder is totally writable.
I tryed putting an alias on httpd.conf but no luck
Could it be an apache permission problem?
Or can I solve the problem within Drupal?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Go to the MAMP console under "**General**" tab, go to the setting for "Run Apache/MySQL server as user".

It should be setting to **www (Apache) / mysql (MySQL)**.
So you need to change it to **username (Apache) / username (MySQL)**.

Save and restart the servers

Refresh the browser, then change it back to **www (Apache) / mysql (MySQL)**, save and restart, and everything should be working

Comment: No luck...Is there an exact way to write the destination for the network folder in flie_copy function?

Comment: No idea, sorry..